# ParseException when running Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where I have to fetch query from JSON file. This query will have a dynamic variable as mentioned below

`"select * from empDF1 where salary > ${sal}"`

I'm assigning the above query from json to a val in spark code.

```
val q1 = "select * from empDF1 where salary > ${sal}"
val sal = 1000
```

But when I run the below code am getting error.

````
val df = spark.sql(s"${q1}")

scala> val df = spark.sql(s"${q1}")
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'(', 'ADD', 'AFTER', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'ANTI', 'ANY', 'ARCHIVE', 'ARRAY', 'AS', 'ASC', 'AT', 'AUTHORIZATION', 'BETWEEN', 'BOTH', 'BUCKET', 'BUCKETS', 'BY', 'CACHE', 'CASCADE', 'CASE', 'CAST', 'CHANGE', 'CHECK', 'CLEAR', 'CLUSTER', 'CLUSTERED', 'CODEGEN', 'COLLATE', 'COLLECTION', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'COMPACT', 'COMPACTIONS', 'COMPUTE', 'CONCATENATE', 'CONSTRAINT', 'COST', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CUBE', 'CURRENT', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'CURRENT_TIME', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'CURRENT_USER', 'DATA', 'DATABASE', DATABASES, 'DBPROPERTIES', 'DEFINED', 'DELETE', 'DELIMITED', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DIRECTORIES', 'DIRECTORY', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'DIV', 'DROP', 'ELSE', 'END', 'ESCAPE', 'ESCAPED', 'EXCEPT', 'EXCHANGE', 'EXISTS', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'EXTENDED', 'EXTERNAL', 'EXTRACT', 'FALSE', 'FETCH', 'FIELDS', 'FILTER', 'FILEFORMAT', 'FIRST', 'FOLLOWING', 'FOR', 'FOREIGN', 'FORMAT', 'FORMATTED', 'FROM', 'FULL', 'FUNCTION', 'FUNCTIONS', 'GLOBAL', 'GRANT', 'GROUP', 'GROUPING', 'HAVING', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'IMPORT', 'IN', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'INNER', 'INPATH', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'INSERT', 'INTERSECT', 'INTERVAL', 'INTO', 'IS', 'ITEMS', 'JOIN', 'KEYS', 'LAST', 'LATERAL', 'LAZY', 'LEADING', 'LEFT', 'LIKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINES', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCAL', 'LOCATION', 'LOCK', 'LOCKS', 'LOGICAL', 'MACRO', 'MAP', 'MATCHED', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'NAMESPACE', 'NAMESPACES', 'NATURAL', 'NO', NOT, 'NULL', 'NULLS', 'OF', 'ON', 'ONLY', 'OPTION', 'OPTIONS', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'OUT', 'OUTER', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', 'OVER', 'OVERLAPS', 'OVERLAY', 'OVERWRITE', 'PARTITION', 'PARTITIONED', 'PARTITIONS', 'PERCENT', 'PIVOT', 'PLACING', 'POSITION', 'PRECEDING', 'PRIMARY', 'PRINCIPALS', 'PROPERTIES', 'PURGE', 'QUERY', 'RANGE', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'RECOVER', 'REDUCE', 'REFERENCES', 'REFRESH', 'RENAME', 'REPAIR', 'REPLACE', 'RESET', 'RESTRICT', 'REVOKE', 'RIGHT', RLIKE, 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'ROLLBACK', 'ROLLUP', 'ROW', 'ROWS', 'SCHEMA', 'SELECT', 'SEMI', 'SEPARATED', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'SESSION_USER', 'SET', 'MINUS', 'SETS', 'SHOW', 'SKEWED', 'SOME', 'SORT', 'SORTED', 'START', 'STATISTICS', 'STORED', 'STRATIFY', 'STRUCT', 'SUBSTR', 'SUBSTRING', 'TABLE', 'TABLES', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'TBLPROPERTIES', TEMPORARY, 'TERMINATED', 'THEN', 'TIME', 'TO', 'TOUCH', 'TRAILING', 'TRANSACTION', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'TRANSFORM', 'TRIM', 'TRUE', 'TRUNCATE', 'TYPE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'UNBOUNDED', 'UNCACHE', 'UNION', 'UNIQUE', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNLOCK', 'UNSET', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'USER', 'USING', 'VALUES', 'VIEW', 'VIEWS', 'WHEN', 'WHERE', 'WINDOW', 'WITH', 'ZONE', '+', '-', '*', '~', STRING, BIGINT_LITERAL, SMALLINT_LITERAL, TINYINT_LITERAL, INTEGER_VALUE, EXPONENT_VALUE, DECIMAL_VALUE, FLOAT_LITERAL, DOUBLE_LITERAL, BIGDECIMAL_LITERAL, IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 36)

== SQL ==
select * from empDF1 where salary >
------------------------------------^^^
```
````

Comment: `val q1 = s"select`

Answer (score 0):

You have not used string interpolation in correct place.

As suggested by @Lamanus in comment section change your code as shown below.

```
val q1 = s"select * from empDF1 where salary > ${sal}"
scala> val df = spark.sql(q1)
```

Comment: Hi, am getting the query from a json file and assigning to a variable. I tried using the string interpolation in json. But that didn't work as am having issues with json syntax. Below is my json element. Its throwing issues because of having 's' before quotes.  Not sure how to add string interpolation in json file. Is there any way that we can add string interpolation in case if we just read the query (from json file) into a variable in spark. Thanks



"valQuery": s"select * from empDF1 where salary > ${sal}"